# Image Source not binding properly in DataTemplate in Windows 8 Mobile

Tags: image, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, datatemplate

I have this list of objects that needs to be separated into two columns. Then I use this template for every object of the list:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UnderlyingRealTimeExchangeRatesLongListSelector">
    <Grid Background="{Binding PriceChanged, Converter={StaticResource PriceChangedToBackgroundConverter}}"
        Margin="0,2.5,5,2.5" Tap="RealTimeElement_Tapped">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtUnderlyingName" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" 
            Style="{StaticResource NormalFontStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="5" FontSize="25" Padding="10" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="1"
            Source="{Binding Path= Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageToFlagConverter}}"
            Height="30"></Image>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtUnderlyingPrice" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='0:N2'}" 
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="#FFD300"
            Style="{StaticResource LightFontStyle}" FontSize="40" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="10"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="llsRealTimeCurrencies1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,15,0,32"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UnderlyingRealTimeExchangeRatesLongListSelector}" 
    Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="llsRealTimeCurrencies2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,15,0,32" 
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UnderlyingRealTimeExchangeRatesLongListSelector}" 
    Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Here is the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    //Returns The flag needed
    if (value != null)
    {
        string image = value.ToString().ToLower();
        string flag = "Assets\\flags\\" + image + "_flag.png";

        return Path.GetFullPath(flag);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Here is the code behind the previous part:

```
private void SetAndShowCorrectRealTimeList<T>(LongListSelector[] list, IList<T> collection)
{
    //and make sure the grid holding the lists is visible
    grdRealtimeLists.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

    List<LongListSelector> lists =
        new List<LongListSelector>()
        {
            llsRealTimeCommodities1,
            llsRealTimeCommodities2,
            llsRealTimeCurrencies1, 
            llsRealTimeCurrencies2,
            llsRealTimeIndecies1,
            llsRealTimeIndecies2,
            llsRealTimeWatchList1,
            llsRealTimeWatchList2
        };

    foreach (var item in lists.Except(list))
    {
        item.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        list[i].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        List<T> result = collection.Where((item, index) => index % 2 == i).ToList();
        list[i].ItemsSource = result;
    }
}
```

The funny part is that it displays the images on the left column, but doesn't on the right. As a matter of fact, it doesn't even gets in the converter for the second column. Thank you!!!

Comment: Just to make that sure, it shows text and image in one LongListSelector, but only text without image in the other one?

Comment: And how does it look like if you replace the Image binding by a fixed image path in the DataTemplate, i.e. the same image for all items. Does that show in the second LongListSelector?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work as well

Comment: Well then it hasn't got to with the binding, right? Are you doing anything else with the elements from the DataTemplate?

Comment: I have figured it out. Thanks

Comment: Then you should add an answer and accept it. That would indicate to others that the problems is solved.

Comment: Thank you, in 2 days though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if your code has all the right elements - 
llsRealTimeCurrencies1, llsRealTimeCurrencies2. Those are the lists that we use to bind the template to:

```
private async void Currencies_Tapped(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.IsWatchListSettingsVisible = false; 
    ApplyForegroundFont(sender, realtimeTabs);
    FrameworkElement parent = (FrameworkElement)((TextBlock)sender).Parent;
    ApplyBackgroundColor(parent, realtimeTabsGrid);
    if (!mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.CurrencyExchangeRates.Any())
    {
         if (mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.Realtime != null &&
             mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.Realtime.Underlyings != null && 
             mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.Realtime.Underlyings.Any())
         {
                 mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.InitializeCurrencies();
         }
         else
         {
                 mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.LoadProductsOrUnderlyingsFromDb<Currency>(mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.CurrencyExchangeRates);
         }
    }
    if (!App.Settings.Contains(currenciesWereSaved))
    {
        App.Settings.Add(currenciesWereSaved, "");
        App.Settings.Save();
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
          mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.SaveUnderlyingsAndProducts<Currency>(mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.CurrencyExchangeRates));
    }
    SetAndShowCorrectRealTimeList(new LongListSelector[] { llsRealTimeCurrencies1, llsRealTimeCurrencies2 }, mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.CurrencyExchangeRates);
    GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendEvent("Real time", "click", "Currencies", 0);

    MyBindableBase.LightstreamerClientInstance.Subscribe(mainViewModel.RealTimeViewModel.CurrencyExchangeRates.Cast<IRealtimeProperty>().ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind image source like this.

```
<Image Grid.Column="1" Height="30">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageToFlagConverter}}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't really work. Behaves the same way. Actually the second column doesn't really gets to the converter.

Comment: Can you share code of left column? Also check out the value of object whether it gets assigned or not.

Comment: I have added the code behind and all objects have the Image value assigned.

Comment: The property path must be an ImageSource

Comment: @MatDevWp8 No, it can as well be a Uri or string. There's built-in conversion.

Comment: if you guys have any clues, it would be really helpful